# Sound device changes to the docking station by default

Tags: 20.04, sound, multiple-monitors, wayland

Ever since I've connected 2 external monitors to my XPS-15 7590, Ubuntu changes the default audio device from the built-in laptop audio device to whatever D3100 Docking station has
[image]

How can I change this so when I reboot my computer, the default speakers are the built-in laptop speakers